# ¿Cómo desactivar o retrasar el manejador de errores en Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

En mi Aplicación controlo el evento Application.ThreadException, el cual detecta errores en la Interfaz de Usuario. En modo Release funciona perfecto, pero cuando se produce un error en modo Debug, el primero en detectar el error es el Visual Studio 2010, por lo que tengo que apretar la tecla F5 para que recién ahí se ejecute el evento Application.ThreadException.
Por esa razón, me gustaría saber cómo desactivar o retrasar el manejador de errores en Visual Studio 2010, con el fin de que el evento Application.ThreadException capture el error antes que el Visual Studio 2010. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Esa opcion la desactivas por medio del menu

> Debug  ->  Exceptions...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el dialogo que visualizaras debes desmarcar de la columna `Thrown` las exception del runtime de .net

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]